# Infinite sum of little-0 is a little-o?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let 
$$
f(x)=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty
f_n(x)
$$
be a real function series such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: f_n(x)=o(g)$

My question is, if is it true that
$$
f(x)=o(g)
$$

Thanks

Comment: What does $o(f)+o(f)$ even mean?

Comment: If you take $o(f)+o(f)=o(f)$ then partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^k o(f)=o(f)$ which implies $\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^k o(f)=o(f)$.

Comment: @kingW3  yes i mean that

Comment: I provided my interpretation of the answer, but that doesn't answer what does $o(f)+o(f)$ mean applied infinitely times. Can you clarify that please? Or at least the motivation for this question?

Comment: i mean a series of function that they are all same little-o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Take $f_n(x)=n\exp(-(x-n)^2)$, or similar "growing bumps moving to infinity". Each of these is bounded (by $n$) and $o(1)$ as $x\to+\infty$, but their sum is not.

Or even try  $f_n(x)=\frac 1{n!}x^n$ and check if summands and series are $o(e^x)$.

Comment: thanks @Hagen von Eitzen  for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Just consider $f_n$ to be chracteristic function of all reals larger than n.
It is bounded by 1. However the sum have groth rate of x.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you may be able to find alternative rates.

If $max_n |f_n(x)| = o(g)$, then you have $\sum_{k=1}^n |f_k(x)| \le n \times max_n |f_n(x)| = o(n \times g )$

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Merudo